# Store PGP keys in HSM

Tags: pgp

Is anyone storing the PGP encryption key in a Hardware Security Module (HSM)? Company policy mandates this, so I need to store the private key to decrypt pgp file in HSM. But as much i know PGP uses its own keyrings what store private and public keys.